# Bootbox.confirm javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I just started learning the Web Development , it would be good if you can help me with this

How can I put bootbox confirm on this code. I tried it lot of times but it shows error like improper end of input.

```
$(".approveBtn").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if (checkRequired("#propertyForm, #uploadcon, #propertyForm2")) {
    var btn = $(this)
    var serial = $("#propertyForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "admin_t/approve_dec",
        data: serial,
        beforeSend: function () {
            btn.prop('disabled', true)
            btn.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == 1) {
                tct();
                upload_docu_by_type(data.prop_id, 'cert_title', 1);
                upload_docu_by_type(data.prop_id, 'tax_dec', 2);
                upload_docu_by_type(data.prop_id, 'rpt_receipt', 3);
                upload_docu_by_type(data.prop_id, 'other_doc', 4, true);
                $.toast({
                    heading: 'Success',
                    text: 'Property Successfully Saved',
                    icon: 'success',
                    loader: false,
                    stack: false,
                    position: 'top-center',
                    allowToastClose: false,
                    bgColor: 'green',
                    textColor: 'white',
                    hideAfter: 6000,
                    afterHidden: function () {
                        location.href = base_url + "/main/tax_dec/" + token
                    }
                });
            } else {
                toast_note(data.message)
            }
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            toast_error(c)
        },
        complete: function () {
            // btn.prop('disabled', false);
            btn.html('Save Details')
        }
    });
}});
```

I already search the documentation. My problem is just the end of bootbox on where to put the `}});`

Comment: show the console. what is the error?

Comment: what's the exact error? Your code will compile, so it's not a syntax problem, I don't think the placement of your brackets is the issue.